# bind/unbind в C#

Tags: c#

Как можно реализовать аналог Bind/Unbind как в jQuery?

```
class MyDataType<T>
{
    private List<T> data;
    ...
    public void Add(T value)
    {
        data.Add(value);
    }
    ...
}

...
MyDataTypeObject.Bind("Add",()=>Console.WriteLine("OnAdd"));
...
MyDataTypeObject.UnBind("Add");
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем прямая реализация байнда, (как и у вас) 
обычно использую ObservableCollection<t>.CollectionChanged

```
 class MyDataType<T>
{
     private ObservableCollection<T> data;
     ....
     data.CollectionChanged += changeHandlerMethod;
}

private void changeHandlerMethod(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("OnAdd");
}
```

Comment: это класс из Reactive Extension, я правильно понял? и как это будет выглядеть в вызывающем коде?

Comment: нет, стандартный .net класс

     System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>

Comment: ясно, но вы походу неправильно меня поняли, мне нужен именно биндовщик.